# Multiple array merge with concat in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need array merge with value concat if array title is same name. my array print is->

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7867867
            [title] => Title1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3452342
            [title] => Title2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1231233
            [title] => Title2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5867867
            [title] => Title1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7867777
            [title] => Title1
        )

)
```

and i want to this format like if title is same concat the array value in one array and other array is removing.

like that->

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7867867,5867867,7867777
            [title] => Title1,Title1,Title1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3452342,1231233
            [title] => Title2,Title2
        )

)
```

If you know that how to solve it please help me!
Thanks

Comment: This isn't difficult to do. Have you tried anything? If so, you need to put it in your question. Otherwise it looks like you're just trying to get us to do your work for you.

Comment: We are not a code service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach($array as $val)
{       
    $titlearray[] = $val['title'];
}
$titlearray = (array_unique($titlearray));

//print_r($titlearray);

foreach($array as $val)
{
    $key = array_search($val['title'], $titlearray); 
    $newarray[$key]['id'][] = $val['id'];
    $newarray[$key]['title'][] = $val['title']; 
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/bEvHE)**

Comment: Thanks Dave,

If possible title is dynamically? 

suppose i add more array title like 'Title3' or 'title4'...

Comment: @Afzal : if more title then use elseif($val['title'] == "Title3") in side foreach

Comment: @Afzal :I edited my answer .